# 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I have had a problem since working with the new MYSQL version 8.0.18.
Always get the same error message:

> SQLSTATE [42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bugtracker1_product_status;
CREATE TABLE bugtracker1_product_status (
    statusID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    productID INT(10),
    statusTitle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    type ENUM('bug','suggestion') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'bug',
    function ENUM('duplicate','solved','outstanding') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'outstanding',
    cssClassName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    showOrder INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    KEY (productID)
);
```

Where is the problem?

```
function ENUM('duplicate','solved','outstanding') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'outstanding',
```

It works in the MariaDB

Thanks for your help!

Thank you for your support, but unfortunately this does not lead to success. The error remains.

```
`function` ENUM('duplicate','solved','outstanding') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'outstanding',
```

Could not prepare statement 'INSERT INTO bugtracker1_product_status (productID, statusTitle, cssClassName, type, function) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'

Is there no alternative?
FUNCTION (R); became reserved in 8.0.1

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an integer declaration is almost meaningless

Comment: Don;t use single quotes around function, use backticks.

Comment: It won't get better through there ;)

Answer (score 1):

`function` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You need to escape it with backticks:

```
 `function` ENUM...
```

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) state that it became reserved in version 8.0.1